# How to scrape price from mercari in google sheet using importxml?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I would like to get the "3,776" price in this website.

https://jp.mercari.com/item/m68422230699

I copy the full xpath, but it returs #N/A
=IMPORTXML("https://jp.mercari.com/item/m68422230699","/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/main/article/div[2]/section[1]/section[1]/div/mer-price//span[2]")

Answer (score 0):

#N/A, in this case, is a result of trying to scrape JavaScript content/elements which Google Sheets does not support. you can test this simply by disabling JS for a given site and what's left can be scraped. in your case it's nothing:

[image]